# It says Server IP address could not be found but site opens normally from Nepal

Tags: dns

Some of my foreign friend says site is not loading whereas its ok from my country Nepal.
Please check http://medicalbasic.net
If its not opening whats da possible reason.

I used free VPN, and found that all the sites on same server doesnot opens. But all sites open from Local Nepal IP.

The problem started from this August 2018, before it was fine.

Comment: Name resolution fails from my end (US residential address, using 8.8.8.8 resolver). What DNS server are you getting the results from, and what DNS records do you obtain, when loading the site from Nepal?

Answer (score 0):

the website can access! But I test it the dns has error .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/He9m7.png)

so, you can contant to your DNS